# In Azure Search, is there a way to scope facet counts to the top parameter?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

If I have an index with 10,000,000 documents and search text and ask to retrieve the top 1,000 items, is there a way to scope the facets to those 1,000 items?

My current problem is:
We have a very large index with a few different facets, including manufacturer.  If I search for a product (WD-40 for instance), that matches a lot of different document and document fields.  It finds the product and it is the top scoring match, but because they only make 1 or 2 products, the manufacturer doesn't show up as a top facet option because it is sorted by count.

Is there a way to scope the facets to the top X documents?  Or, is there a way to only grab documents which are above a certain @search.score?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of a refiner is to give users options to narrow down the result set. I would say the $top parameter and returned facets works as it should. Trying to limit the number of refiners to be based on the top 1000 results is a bad idea when we think about it. You'll end up with confusing usability- and recall issues.

Your query for WD-40 returns a large result set. So large that there are 155347 unique manufacturers listed. I'm guessing you have several million hits. The intent of that query is to return the products called WD-40 (my assumption). But, since you search all properties in all types of content, you end up with various products like doors, hinges, and bikes that might have some text saying that "put some WD-40 on it to stop squeaks".

I'm guessing that most of the hits you get are irrelevant. Thus, you should either limit the scope of your initial query by default. For example, limit to searching only the title property. Or add a filter to exclude a category of documents (like manuals, price lists, etc.).

You could also consider submitting different queries from your frontend application. One narrowly scoped query that retrieves the refiners and another, broader query that returns the results.

Comment: Thanks Dan.  I think what we're going to do is remove the count from the UI and then build the facet list as a combination of highest manufacturer count hit + the manufacturers from the top of the results list.  I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a relevant data set to test on, but I believe the $top parameter might do what you want. See this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents#top-optional

That said, there are other approaches to solve your use case.

**Normalize your data**
I don't know how clean your data is. But, for any data set of this size, it's common that the manufacturer name is not consistent. For example, your manufacturer may be listed as

- WD40 Company
- WD-40 Company
- WDFC
- WD 40
- WD-40 Inc.
- ...

Normalizing will greatly reduce the number of values in your refiners. It's probably not enough for your use case, but still worth doing.

**Consider adding more refiners**

When you have a refiner with too many options it's always a good idea to consider having more refiner with course values. For example a category or perhaps a simple refiner that splits the results in two. Like a "Physical vs. Digital" product as a first choice. Or consumer vs. professional product. In stock or on back-order. This pattern allows users to quickly reduce the result set without having to use the brand refiner.

**Categorize your refiner with too many options**

In your case, your manufacturer refiner contained too many options. I have seen examples where people add a search box within the refiner. Another option is to group your refiner options in buckets. For text values like a manufacturer, you could generate a new property with the first character of the manufacturer's name. That way you could present a refiner that lets users select a manufacturer from A-Z.

Comment: I thought the $top parameter would work as well, but it doesn't seem to.  This query for example: $top=10&facet=manufacturerAlts/manufacturerName brings back 10 search results, but the facet section of the response isn't scoped to those 10.      "@search.facets": {
        "manufacturerAlts/manufacturerName": [
            {
                "count": 155347,
                "value": "SCRUBBED"
            }   -- We are normalizing names and matching to a top level with tf-idf / stopwords, this is just a very large data set. A-Z buckets may be a valid option.